# ANT task to move and rename, files and folders, recursively

Tags: java, ant, move, fileset

I have have a folder structure like so:

```
/PROJECT/PROJECT.html

/PROJECT/PROJECT_readme.txt

/PROJECT/PROJECT.css

/PROJECT/PROJECT.js

/PROJECT/abc_PROJECT_def.txt

/PROJECT/something.js

/PROJECT/other.txt

/PROJECT/somefolder/PROJECT_other.txt
```

I want to use ANT to copy the complete directory and also change the PROJECT string in the files or folder to a specified value e.g. mysuperproject, so the result folder structure is so :

```
/mysuperproject/mysuperproject.html

/mysuperproject/mysuperproject_readme.txt

/mysuperproject/mysuperproject.css

/mysuperproject/mysuperproject.js

/mysuperproject/abc_mysuperproject_def.txt

/mysuperproject/something.js

/mysuperproject/other.txt

/mysuperproject/somefolder/mysuperproject_other.txt
```

Is there a easy way to do that in ANT ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Move task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/move.html) should suit you. Read the linked docs carefully.

It's a core task, so you can use it without downloading of configuring anything.

Comment: I tried this but I can't seem to get that to work :
<move todir="templates">
  <fileset dir="${templates.dir}">
    <include name="**/*"/>
  </fileset>
   <regexpmapper from="(.*)PROJECT(.*)$$" to="\1mysuperproject\2"/>
</move>

Comment: and what happens? any concrete error? I think you shouldn't expect others to write your ant task ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement.  This is what I did:

```
  <target name="move-and-rename" description="Move and Rename">
        <copy todir="${toDir}" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
            <fileset dir="${fromDir}" includes="**" />
            <regexpmapper from="(.*)${fromName}(.*)" to="\1${toName}\2"/>
         </copy>             
  </target>
```

Invoke on command line as

```
ant move-and-rename -DfromName=project -DtoName=xxxproject -DfromDir=. -DtoDir=proj2
```

Hope it helps somebody else.